# Swift Region Monitoring Local Notification trigger

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, geofencing, clcircularregion

I'm doing an app to trigger a local notification when a region is entered.
However, sometimes when the phone is locked, the notifications didn't pop up even I've been in the region area for a while. The notification popup will show only when the power/home button is pressed(phone still in locked mode).

In general, all seems to be working except that sometimes the notification will show only when power/home button is pressed to awake the phone although it is still locked.

Hope someone can enlighten me please! =)

Comment: are you using `BackgroundFetch` for this?

Comment: Yes Background Fetch is enabled in the "Capabilities". The region monitoring is working even when I terminal/close the application. The weird part is that sometimes the notification popup only appear when the power/home button is pressed but phone is still in locked mode. =(

Comment: are you using `standard location service` or `significant-change location service`?

Comment: I used locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region) for the region monitoring, but I don't use self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation().

Answer (score 0):

According to the developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html). In core-location framework, two services can give you the current location information.

> 1. The standard location service is a configurable, general-purpose solution for getting location data and tracking location changes for the specified level of accuracy.
> 2. The significant-change location service delivers updates only when there has been a significant change in the device’s location, such as 500 meters or more.

You need to use standard location services to keep monitoring location in background

> If your iOS app must keep monitoring location even while it’s in the background, use the standard location service and specify the location value of the UIBackgroundModes key to continue running in the background and receiving location updates. (In this situation, you should also make sure the location manager’s pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property is set to YES to help conserve power.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there's one more method that is mentioned in the developer documentation. That is the Region monitoring that I'm using here.
- Region monitoring lets you monitor boundary crossings for defined geographical regions and Bluetooth low-energy beacon regions. (Beacon region monitoring is available in iOS only.)